# Get current keystate?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get current key state for key ALT? 
But its not work,why?

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


bool KeyPressed(short p_key)
{

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(p_key) & 0x8000)
    {
        std::cout << "KEYPRESSED";
        return true;

    }
    else return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test";
    while (true)
    {
        KeyPressed(0x4A);
    }

    std::cout << "";
}
```

It should get the state everytime it check,but its not at all

Comment: Stop using magic numbers!!!

Comment: `0x4A` is the `J` key, not the ALT key, which is `0x12` instead. Use the `VK_MENU` [virtual key code constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_MENU) & 0x8000))
{
    // ALT key is down.
}
```

*VK_MENU* is the virtual-key code for the ALT key

Found this information in following article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input